# Subgroups of the Torsion Subgroup of an Elliptic Curve

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups, pronunciation

A silly question.

I am working through Silverman and Tate, *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*

> Let $E$ be an elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation $$E:y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c, \quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}.$$
>    Let $$E[n]=\{(x_1,y_1) , \cdot \cdot \cdot , (x_m,y_m) , \mathcal{O} \}$$be the complete set of points of $E(\mathbb{C})$ of order dividing $n$.

How do you say "$E[n]$"? Do you say "the set of points of order dividing $n$"? Or do you say "$E$ of $n$"?

Comment: You could say the $n-$torsion subgroup or the group of $n-$torsion points.

Comment: Thanks, I am giving a presentation soon and I realized could write it but didn't know how to say it :)

Comment: If I were giving a talk where some in the audience weren't familiar with the subject, I might refer to it as the kernel of multiplication by $n$ on the elliptic curve.

Comment: I say "n-torsion subgroup" or simply "n-torsion".